# Constrained Optimization doesn't converge?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Given a $n\times J$ matrix $T$ with strictly positive elements, I'm trying to obtain the values ($\lambda_i$) that minimize $\sum T_{ij}\lambda_i^{\alpha_i}$ with the constraints $\lambda_i \geq 0$ and $\sum \lambda_i = 1$ for each of the $J$ columns. Provided $\alpha_i \geq 1$, the problem has a unique solution such that $\lambda_i > 0$, so only constraint $\sum \lambda_i = 1$ will be binding. I have used

```
Alpha=4/3
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}}
tecniques = Dimensions[T][[1]]
factors = Dimensions[T][[2]]
AlphaVec = ConstantArray[Alpha, tecniques]
LambdaVec = Array[Lambda, tecniques]
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, tecniques]
maxmin = Table[LambdaVec /. Minimize[{(Transpose[T].LambdaVec^(AlphaVec))[[i]],
     onesVec.LambdaVec == 1}, LambdaVec][[2]], {i, 1, factors}]
```

And this works fine when $\alpha=2$. However, when I set $\alpha=\frac{4}{3}$, Mathematica fails to return an answer, just keeps running. I'm sure there is some problem in my code, but I cannot see it (also, it looks kind of awkard to me). I've computed the solutions manually and it did not take long. Of course, this is an example and I'd like the code to work for arbitrary $n>J,\alpha_i$ and $T$.

Comment: Please check your syntax. The code does not run at all.

Comment: You're right, I skipped the definition of $\alpha$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing  `Minimize` by `NMinimize` . You will see that in the process of computation at $\alpha =4/3$ complex numbers are encountered. It is necessary to add the restrictions of $\lambda\ge 0$

```
T = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}};
Alpha = 4/3;
tecniques = Dimensions[T][[1]];
factors = Dimensions[T][[2]];
AlphaVec = ConstantArray[Alpha, tecniques];
LambdaVec = Array[Lambda, tecniques];
onesVec = ConstantArray[1, tecniques];
h = (Transpose[T].LambdaVec^(AlphaVec));
maxmin = Table[
   LambdaVec /. 
    NMinimize[{h[[i]], {onesVec.LambdaVec == 1, 
        Table[Lambda[i] >= 0, {i, 1, tecniques}]}}, LambdaVec][[
     2]], {i, 1, factors}] // Quiet
{{0.201207, 0.0314277, 0.767365}, {0.239077, 0.683654, 0.077269}}
```

This task has an exact solution, which the author indicated and which can easily be found using the Mathematica. But it does not coincide with the numerical solution that we found using  `NMinimize`. We consider the function 
`h={2 Lambda[1]^(4/3) + 3 Lambda[2]^(4/3) + Lambda[3]^(4/3), 
 3 Lambda[1]^(4/3) + 2 Lambda[2]^(4/3) + 4 Lambda[3]^(4/3)}`, find its extrema, using the standard analysis. Put `h[[1]]=q, h[[2]]=q1, Lambda[1]=x,Lambda[2]=y`, using constraints, we find

```
q = 2*x^(4/3) + 3*y^(4/3) + (1 - x - y)^(4/3); q1 = 
 3*x^(4/3) + 2*y^(4/3) + 4*(1 - x - y)^(4/3);
```

Necessary conditions for an extremum

```
eq = {D[q, x] == 0, D[q, y] == 0} // FullSimplify
Out[]= {9 x + y == 1, x + 28 y == 1}

 Solve[eq, {x, y}]

Out[]={{x -> 27/251, y -> 8/251}}
eq1 = {D[q1, x] == 0, D[q1, y] == 0} // FullSimplify

Out[]= {91 x + 64 y == 64, 8 x + 9 y == 8}

 Solve[eq1, {x, y}]

Out[]= {{x -> 64/307, y -> 216/307}}
```

The third value is found as `Lambda[3]=1-x-y`. And so we got the exact solution, which the author indicated in the comments. Now we need to get a numerical solution that would not be as rude as we indicated above using `NMinimize`.
I will indicate a simple solution to the problem. We use a special method

```
maxmin2 = 
 Table[LambdaVec /. 
    NMinimize[{h[[i]], {onesVec.LambdaVec == 1, 
        Table[Lambda[i] >= 0, {i, 1, tecniques}]}}, LambdaVec, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxIterations -> 100, 
      Method -> "RandomSearch"][[2]], {i, 1, factors}] 
{{0.10756972111553840466091432374, 0.0318725099601588814911179025068, 
  0.860557768924302713847967773754}, {0.20846905537459283387622149837,
 0.703583061889250814332247557003, 0.0879478827361563517915309446257}}
```

We compare it with the exact solution

```
{{27/251, 8/251, 216/251}, {64/307, 216/307, 27/307}}*1.`30

{{0.107569721115537848605577689243, 0.0318725099601593625498007968127, 
  0.860557768924302788844621513944},{0.208469055374592833876221498371,
 0.703583061889250814332247557003, 0.0879478827361563517915309446254}}
```

And so, we numerically reproduced the exact solution with an error of $10^{-15}$.

Comment: I was just about to write the same... (+1)

Comment: It was obvious, but the code contains a typo. You need to fix the code, and then add restrictions. But still in the process of computation, complex numbers are encountered. So I added `Quiet`.

Comment: Here's another way to get these results: `NArgMin[#.(v^(4/3)), v ∈ RegionIntersection[Hyperplane[{1, 1, 1}, 1], ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, IdentityMatrix[3]]]] & /@ Transpose[T]`

Comment: @J. M. is somewhat okay It's funny, your code gives a similar warning 'NArgMin::nrnum: The function value 1.30754 -0.334771 I is not a real number at {Subscript[v, 1],Subscript[v, 2],Subscript[v, 3]} = {-0.291501,0.0796861,1.21182}`.

Comment: Yes, it's funny that `NMinimize[]` (and thus `NArgMin[]` as well) still evaluates outside a constraint region even when it's not supposed to. I have also tried using `Surd[v, 3]^4` instead, but got different results, and was not sufficiently motivated to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I tried the approach you suggested and obtained the same values that you report. However, the solution is different from the one that I expected {{27/251,8/251,216/251},{64/307,216/307,27/307}}

Comment: @Patricio How did you find these solutions?

Comment: Paper and pencil, like in the old days

Comment: @Patricio Indeed, I counted the minimum of the function `h` and got these values. Now we need to understand why Mathematica finds other values.

Comment: ah, that was what I was talking about when I replaced `v^(4/3)` with `Surd[v, 3]^4`.

Comment: Also, in the process @AlexTrounev describes for the exact solution, a) No complex numbers arise, b) There is no need for the non-negativity constraints.

Comment: @Patricio I added a special method that numerically reproduced the exact solution with an error of $10^{-15}$